# String difference windows and linux

Tags: c#

Would someone convert /state how to represent the string (path) below from Linux to windows

"C:/Users /xxxx/Desktop/song.mp3"

It's a string sent from my Android app to a winform,  for some reasons winform c# dosent recognize that string as path to a file.

Error I get in winform if "invalid character in the path"

Comment: windows uses backslashes. `c:\users\....`

Comment: Well the file will not exist due to the space after Users .... Forwards slashes work perfectly well in windows.

Comment: How it "dosent recognize"? What do you do in that winforms app? Show some code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a link to a discussion of the difference between windows vs linux file systems:

[howtogeek 6 ways the linux file system is different from the windows file system](http://www.howtogeek.com/137096/6-ways-the-linux-file-system-is-different-from-the-windows-file-system/)

So your path would be

C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\song.mp3

Comment: Am not on Linux desktop,  and the forward slash was actually a backlash(my phone keyboard has no backslash).  I will try to restate my problem,   the string "C:/Users/xxxx/Deskstop/song.mp3" was first sent from my winform app to an Android app. The same string was sent from my Android to the winform app but this time the winform c# dosent recognize it as a path.